# custom shipping address date field validation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, shipping, magento2.1.6

I've added a custom field to the shipping address in checkout:

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['date'] = [
            'component' => '<vendor>_<module>/js/shipping-provider',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => '<vendor>_<module>/date',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'date'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.date',
            'label' => __('Date'),
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true
            ],
            'sortOrder' => 200,
            'id' => 'date'
        ];
```

As you can see I set `required-entry` to `true` for validation purposes. But now I always get that the field is a required field error message even though the field has a value set.

Here is the field:

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    hasFocus: focused,
    datepicker: { storage: value, options: options },
    attr: {
        value: value,
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        disabled: disabled
    }" readonly/>
```

Any idea on this?

**Update**
Here is the shipping-provider.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'jquery',
    'mage/calendar'
], function (Abstract, $, calendar) {
    'use strict';

    $.extend(true, $, {
        calendarConfig: {
            onSelect: function (date, datepicker) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    });

    return Abstract.extend(Abstract, calendar);
});
```

Comment: Can you post your js component? `<vendor>_<module>/js/shipping-provider`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Doesn't matter. It's the same behaviour with the abstract provider `'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'`.
The problem is just the `'required-entry' => true` line. If I comment that, everything works as expected. Data is transferred to the quote and then saved to the order.

Comment: damn...I checked again just to be 100% sure and it seems I ran into a caching problem. It really is the shipping-provider :O
I'll attach a stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So extending from abstract has proven to be not working. I have to extend from `date` (makes sense).
So this is working just fine:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date',
], function ($, date) {
    'use strict';

    return date;
});
```

Problem is now I need to extend the calendar itself and if I do so it is not working again:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date',
], function ($, date) {
    'use strict';

    $.extend(true, $, {
        calendarConfig: {
            onSelect: function (date, datepicker) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    });

    return date;
});
```

The problem is that `onSelect` interferes with internal Magento functions. Extending with changing other values like `minDate` works.
So I have to do this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date',
], function ($, date) {
    'use strict';

    $.extend(true, $, {
        calendarConfig: {
            minDate: getMinDate()
        }
    });

    return date.extend({
        onValueChange: function (value) {
            // do stuff here instead
        }
    });
});
```